# Zebra RFID Integration Error: com.zebra.rfid.api3.OperationFailureException

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application, rfid, zebra

Zebra RFID device after getting disconnected, I can not reconnect unless I charge Zebra device again and then use it. I'm getting this error:

```
D/RFIDAPI3Error( 3867): connected RFD850019240520100016
E/MainActivity( 3867): Error initializing RFID reader
E/MainActivity( 3867): com.zebra.rfid.api3.OperationFailureException
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.zebra.rfid.api3.r1.a(Unknown Source:11)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.zebra.rfid.api3.RFIDReader.a(Unknown Source:213)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.zebra.rfid.api3.RFIDReader.connect(Unknown Source:176)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.apptricity.asset_mobile.MainActivity.initializeAndConnect(MainActivity.java:112)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.apptricity.asset_mobile.MainActivity.lambda$configureFlutterEngine$0$com-apptricity-asset_mobile-MainActivity(MainActivity.java:29)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.apptricity.asset_mobile.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:2)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MainActivity( 3867):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```